# Retrieve data and wait time to check if something new appeared in database

Tags: java, database, jms, h2, spring-jms

I would like to retrieve data from my in-memory H2 database via rest endpoint using Spring and Java8. I have 2 endpoints: one to retrieve data, and second one to add data to database.

How can I achieve something like it is described below in easiest way? I am not sure what solution can be better I thought about JMS Queue or CompletableFuture (if it is possible). It should work for few users, they will call to retrieve data saved under their id number.

Scenario:

1. User calls rest-endpoint to retrieve data.
2. If data is present in database then it is retrieved and returned to user.
3. If data is not present in database then connection is hold for 60 seconds and if during that time something will appear in database (added via endpoint to add new data) then data will be returned.
4. If data is not present in database and new data won’t appear in 60 seconds then endpoint returns no content.

Answer (score 0):

There were multiple ways of doing that and if requirements is clear then i suggest below two approaches.

Approach 1:

1. Find and retrieve if data available without waiting.
2. If data not available set resource id and retrieveTime in header and respond to consumer.
3. Based resource id you can be ready with data if available.
4. In this way you can sure about your endpoint service time always consistent and ideally it shouldn't be more than 3 seconds.

Approach 2.

1. if data not available then out sleep in 60 seconds (not in database connection scope) and then again try with same thread.
2. Don't need any queue or ansyc process here.
3. Here your loosing resources and service time would take more.

Apart from other approaches, if your systems using eventing then use eventing approach when there is record persistent then send event to consumer (all database has the feature to send event to source system today).